# Logo doesn't fit in bootstrap navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to change the image in my naviation to a larger size.

However by doing this the navbar get's malformed.

[image]

I have the code over here: http://www.bootply.com/941lMP3fj6#

The problem might be that the image is in an anchor tag. But not sure.

Answer (score 14):

Try:

```
.navbar-brand 
{
    padding-top: 0;
}
```

Working: http://www.bootply.com/cCg5FvZyZP

Comment: This is right.  You have/had `padding: 15px 15px;`.  Changing it to `padding: 0 15px 15px 15px;` would take away just the top also while keeping the other paddings.

Comment: looking at your solution, there now seems to be an ugly 1px boarder followed by 20px of bottom padding - is that by design?

Comment: @StevenP This is what OP posted :))

Answer (score 4):

Add this to your styles:

```
.navbar-brand
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
{

.navbar-brand img
{
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

http://www.bootply.com/rAzwwIbCBI

Answer (score 2):

You need to adjust the height of the navbar.

You can use this variable in LESS to adjust the height and it will center the navbar vertically and include all necessary padding:

```
@navbar-height
```

50px is the default.

How to adjust this in regular CSS is to change the `min-height` of `.navbar` and the height of `navbar-fixed-top` and then adjust padding of `.navbar-nav`.

This is how the top part should be structured (missing navbar-header):

```
    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="container">
               <div class="navbar-header">
                <button class="navbar-toggle" data-target=".navbar-responsive-collapse" data-toggle="collapse" type="button">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" rel="home" href="/" title="www.site.nl">                        
                    <img src="//placehold.it/200x51">
                </a>
              </div>
```

Example Bootply: http://www.bootply.com/tOoeM8o8Om

Comment: When the linked solution is collapsed, the drop-down menu appears on-top of the image

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="container">
                <button class="navbar-toggle" data-target=".navbar-responsive-collapse" data-toggle="collapse" type="button">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>

                <div class="navbar navbar-collapse collapse navbar-responsive-collapse">
                    <div class="pull-left" style="margin-right: 15px;">
                         <a rel="home" href="/" title="www.site.nl">

                    <img src="//placehold.it/200x51">
                </a>
                    </div>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class="active"><a href="">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Link 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Link 2</a></li>
                    </ul> <!-- end nav-->
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><strong class="caret"></strong> Select language</a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
                                <li><a href="">NL</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">IL</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">ENG</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul> <!-- end nav menu right -->
                </div> <!-- end nav-collapse -->

            </div>
```

Put your logo inside the container.

The above code works!!

Check and let me know if you have any issues!!